# Javascript object key value coding.  Dynamically setting a nested value

Tags: javascript, object, key-value-observing, key-value-coding

I'm working on a little library that lets me do some basic key value coding with objects.  Say I have the following object:

```
var data = { key1: "value1", key2: { nested1: 1, nested2: "wowza!" } };
```

And I have the following JavaScript function:

```
var setData = function(path, value) {
    eval("data." + path + "= value;");
};
```

And in use:

```
setData("key1", "updated value1"); // data.key1 == "updated value1"
setData("key2.nested1", 99); // data.key2.nested1 == 99
```

This works, however I would like to accomplish the above without using `eval`.  Is this possible, or is `eval` the best way to go?

**EDIT:**

**NOTE** it can be assumed the value you're setting exists, at least for path depth - 1.  I'm more concerned about setting the value of an existing object.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Recursion is what you need:

```
function setData(key,val,obj) {
  if (!obj) obj = data; //outside (non-recursive) call, use "data" as our base object
  var ka = key.split(/\./); //split the key by the dots
  if (ka.length < 2) { 
    obj[ka[0]] = val; //only one part (no dots) in key, just set value
  } else {
    if (!obj[ka[0]]) obj[ka[0]] = {}; //create our "new" base obj if it doesn't exist
    obj = obj[ka.shift()]; //remove the new "base" obj from string array, and hold actual object for recursive call
    setData(ka.join("."),val,obj); //join the remaining parts back up with dots, and recursively set data on our new "base" obj
  }    
}

setData("key1", "updated value1"); // data.key1 == "updated value1"
setData("key2.nested1", 99); // data.key2.nested1 == 99
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 100 times - it was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: **Thank you** so very much! I can't begin to tell you how much this has helped me.

Comment: This is a great answer. I made a version without `obj` argument and with ES6 syntax for legibility. https://gist.github.com/sungwoncho/8caf7f3d9e56741c0631cda134e01832

Comment: *Thank you* so much. You save my day!

Answer (score 4):

Yep, it's easy. `obj.prop = val` is the same as `obj['prop'] = val` so you can rewrite setData as this:

```
var setData = function (path, value) {
    data[path] = value;
};
```

And that should do it.

However, I am not sure how much success you will have with the 3rd level (if that makes sense.) obj.prop.prop can't be referenced by obj['prop.prop'] and will instead have to be referenced by obj['prop']['prop'], so setData would have to be rewritten to take that into account. I'm not having much luck with that, though.

Edit: I have made one that (for me) sets it nested how you want, but no further than that. Unfortunately, if you are nesting deeper than your examples then I don't see a real reason to abandon `eval`. I have not done any benchmarks, but at some point the calculations will be more computationally expensive than even `eval` (which is pretty hard to accomplish.)

This is what I came up with, which will set them at least 1 'level' deep; that is, it will work with `key2.nested1` but not `key2.nested1.i_love_nesting`, if that makes sense:

```
var setData = function (path, value) {
    if (path.indexOf('.') != -1) {
        path = path.split('.');
        for (var i = 0, l = path.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (typeof(data[path[i]]) === 'object') {
                continue;
            } else {
                data[path[i - 1]][path[i]] = value;
            }
        }
    } else {
        data[path] = value;
    }
};
```

Hope this helps. I might not have written this in the most efficient way, though...

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for nested values.  In your example:

setData("prop.nestedProp", "val");

Will result in the following data json:
{ "prop.nestedProp": "val" }

I want:
{ prop: { nestedProp: "val" } }

Comment: Yeah, I caught that a few seconds after I submitted the post. Took me a bit to get a nice, working function, but that one above should do. An alternative choice for your library might be to let them access the 'object' directly - i.e. let them access `my_json_object.foo.bar`.

Comment: The full function (excluded for simplicity) will trigger an event if the value has changed.

<code>
app.dataSet = function(path, value) {
  if (app.dataGet(path) == value)
    return value;
  
  eval("app._data." + path + "= value;");
  app.trigger("data." + path);
  return app.dataGet(path);
};
</code>

Unfortunately this needs to work at an arbitrary depth.  I was hoping there might be a nice solution to the problem, let the get function (will have to test if it is faster then using eval too).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired from @user1416920 I made this one :

```
function setData(key,val,obj)
{
    keys = key.split(/\./);
    last = keys.pop();

    keys.forEach(function(key)
    {
      if(typeof obj[key] === "undefined")
        obj[key] = {}; 
      obj = obj[key]; 
    });

    obj[last] = val;
}
```

What it does is pretty self explanatory ^^.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setData(key,val,obj){
    keys = key.split(/\./);
    to_set = keys.pop();
    keys.forEach(function(obj_name){ obj = obj[obj_name]; });
    obj[to_set] = val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem becomes easier and more natural to solve if you can be flexible in how you're specifying your path.  If instead of doing something like `key2.nested1` you can do `{key2:{nested1:{}}}` (object notation), it becomes fairly trivial:

```
function setData(subtree, path){
    var nodeName = Object.keys(path);

    if(typeof path[nodeName] == 'object')
        setData(subtree[nodeName], path[nodeName]);
    else
        subtree[nodeName] = path[nodeName];
}

var data = { key1: "value1", key2: { nested1: 1, nested2: "wowza!" } };

// For the initial call, 'subtree' is the full data tree
setData(data, {key2:{nested1:99}});
```

You're simply recursing into the 2nd arg of the `setData` call, until you find the value.  Each time you recurse, you step down into the `data` tree at the specified point.

This function can easily be modified to accept the dot notation you specified, too, but to me this is a cleaner and more natural approach (plus, String ops are slow).

Cheers