# How to call setState in react with nested objects and unknown key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My state looks like this

```
state = {
  basic: {
    entry: 'index.js',
    output: {
      path: 'dist',
      filename: 'bundle.js',
    }
  }
}
```

I have defined a callback for input onChange event :

```js
handleUpdateString = (e) => {
  const name = e.target.name
  const value = e.target.value
  this.setState({ [name]: value })
  console.log(this.state)
}
```

say my input name is 'basic.entry'

my state is updated, but instead of having `this.state.basic` be `{ entry: 'some value'}`

I end up with a new key in my state : `{ basic.entry: 'some value' }`

I have tried using `dot-object` to convert the dot-seperated string to a nested object, and passing this to `setState` but the state appears to be unchanged.

What are simple solutions to this problem ?

Comment: Try `this.setState({ name: value })`;

Answer (score 0):

Use a switch statement with explicit setState.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a React question but a pure JavaScript question on how to set a nested property on any object using a dot-notated string for the property. There is an answer here: [Javascript object key value coding.  Dynamically setting a nested value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061325/javascript-object-key-value-coding-dynamically-setting-a-nested-value)

Using that example in React:

```
handleUpdateString = (e) => {
  const name = e.target.name
  const value = e.target.value
  const state = Object.assign({}, this.state);
  setData(name, value, state);
  this.setState(state);
  console.log(this.state)
}
```